# Symfony 4 ROLE_USER to ROLE_ADMIN with database

Tags: symfony, roles, symfony4

I am learning Symfony 4 and i want to change role of somes users to ROLE_ADMIN.

How can do this with a database ?

I tried to change it manually in database but it doesn't work...

(a:1:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}  ->  a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";})

Thank you ;)

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: did you re-login, because that's potentially required that the role change becomes effective?

Comment: thank you for your reply :)   It's weird because now it's working... i had an error like " error 17 to 23 bytes"  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To promote users you can use command lines tools for FosUser:

```
    php bin/console fos:user:promote testuser --super
    php bin/console fos:user:promote testuser ROLE_ADMIN
```

check the doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html

Comment: For curiosity, from where did you understand he is using FosUser?

Comment: because the two mentioned roles are somehow 'standard rules' coming with FOSUserBundle - would be surprising if he didn't use it.

Comment: @LBA - ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN are actually part of the Symfony security component.  At least in the docs.

Comment: @LBA Cerad preceded me in the answer but anyway (in simple applications) that role's names are quite common also if you don't use FosUser.

Comment: Hi :) thank you for your reply :) i don't use FosUser because i thinked it was not officialy available in Symfony 4.